# Python 2.7 CSV writing format not correct

Tags: python, csv, formatting

I am currently trying to get a leader board working. The leader board will only store the score. I am trying to write the scores to the csv file. Here is my code for the write:

```
if col:
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        w.writerow(str(curr_score) + "\n")
    crashed = True
```

When this is run the csv file ends up like this: https://gyazo.com/19c9007827498fb5cf847535167d5841

I think it has to do with the score being converted into a string, but when I do not convert the score I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Desktop\Computing Project\Galaxian.py", line 173, in <module>
    w.writerow(curr_score + "\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

This is the first time I have been working with csv files in Python so I have probably made a small silly mistake but any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just remove `+ "\n"` and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add linebreaks (`\n`) yourself. The `csv.writer` will do that for you.

```
if col:
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "ab") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        w.writerow(curr_score)
    crashed = True
```

---

The odd result you get when you convert `curr_score` to a string is because a string in python is iterable (you can say `for char in "abc":`).  `writerow` is set up to accept an iterable, creating one field in the row for each member of the iterable.  So `writerow` is thinking you want a number of columns, each containing one character.

If you want to add a string as the only element on a row, you need to enclose it in another iterable, for instance, a tuple:

```
if col:
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "ab") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",")
        w.writerow((str(curr_score),)) #note the extra brackets and comma
    crashed = True
```

Comment: I tried this code and it has sorted the spacing of the numbers, but there is still a gap between each row. https://gyazo.com/f308088038cc214588918c7aba40cb9f
Could you help me with this issue too please if you know why this is happening, either way thank you for managing explaining to me why the numbers were all spaced out.

Comment: @HarryBeggs The code you posted only writes one value.  Please post the code that writes the second number too.

Comment: That screen shot was after two runs, there is not any other writes. Thanks

Edit: Just ran it a third time and there is still that space occurring.

Comment: The `csv.writer` adds an extra newline as a sort of "end of file" marker, from what I can tell.  You either need to keep the file and writer open until you're finished entirely, or open the file in overwrite mode (`w`), rather than append.

Comment: Ok, I think what I'll do is read the file into the program as a list, append the list then overwrite the csv with the appended list, thank you for the help.

Comment: @HarryBeggs You should also try using `"ab"` mode when opening the file.